# What is the best way to remove an element from a dense array with V8?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-chrome, v8

Google V8 engine has a different internal representation for dense and sparse arrays. When an array goes from dense to sparse it causes dictionary mode to kick in, which is much slower.

I can't seem to figure out what is the most efficient (fastest) way to remove an element from somewhere in a dense array to avoid going to a sparse array.

The use case is very simple. Starting with an array `[8, 6, 1]` and remove the element `6` to go to `[8, 1]`.

Comment: If you're scared to become sparse, which I'm not sure why unless you target only V8 users, know exactly your array and are convinced this will have a relevant impact in performances, you could just set `null` or any specific value to that index which you would ignore in other operations.

Comment: That isn't a sparse array, `[8,,1]` is. If you want to remove the member and retain a "dense" array, use [*Array.prototype.splice*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12). If you want remaining members to keep their current index, then use *delete*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're removing just one element, `shift()` is fastest if the element is at the beginning of the array, `pop()` is fastest when the element is at the end of the array, and [`spliceOne`](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/blob/7061669dba26337e47e258385dd58e400881dff1/lib/events.js#L409-L414) is usually fastest if the element is somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for the [`splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which removes or replaces parts of an array. In your case:

```
var arr = [8, 6, 1];
arr.splice(1, 1); // at pos 1 remove 1 element, yields [6]
arr; // [8, 1]
```